# How to download an encoded asset (any type of file) in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my React app, I have an API to get the file by sending the file URL. After I receiving the file, I need to download it as the original file. This should be applicable to any type of file. When I call the API, I'm getting the encoded text of the file from the back end. I'm using the **react-file-saver** module to download the file. **The problem is, the module downloads a text file instead of the real file.**

This is how the GET API response looks

```
IHDRÄõWìã¢sRGB®Îé–eXIfMM*>F(‡iNÄ õASCIIScreenshotÞK|    pHYs%%IR$ðÖiTXtXML:com.adobe.xmp<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="........
```

This is the Function for the download

```
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

downloadFile = (url) => {
        API.get(`/main/download?fileUrl=${url}`, { headers: { 'Accept': 'application/*' } })
            .then(res => {
                var file = new File([res.data], { type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8" });
                saveAs(file);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error("AXIOS ERROR: ", err);
            })
    }
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: In the second argument to File object you're explicitly setting the type to type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8". Try applying correct type and try again

Comment: @maaajo even I set `{ type: "image/*" }` for a PNG, still the file is downloading as a text

Comment: Ok. Then I'm thinking something is incorrect with the File object. Why are you creating it this way? Perhaps you could try directly downloading the file out of the response like this: ```saveAs(res.blob(), filename)``` ?

Comment: @maaajo then it says, `res.blob is not a function`

Comment: Sorry didn't notice that you're using axios as your fetch function. Can you then try adding ```responseType: 'blob'``` to the second argument object of API.get and try ```saveAs(res, filename)```, so: ```API.get(`/main/download?fileUrl=${url}`, { headers: { 'Accept': 'application/*' }, responseType: 'blob })
            .then(res => {
                saveAs(res, yourFileName);
            })```